# Capturing a photo taken from a gallery intent

Tags: android

I have a method which launches the gallery so that I can choose photos (this works)

```
public ArrayList<ImageEntry> pickImages(Context cont){
    Picker.PickListener pic = new MyPickListener();
    ArrayList<ImageEntry> images = new ArrayList<>();
    pic.onPickedSuccessfully(images);
    new Picker.Builder(cont, pic, R.style.MIP_theme)
            .build()
            .startActivity();
    return images;
}
```

Except when I take a photo in gallery it returns with

```
/storage/emulated/0/capture1461208914080.png
```

As the image path

When I try to load this image

```
  public class MyPickListener implements Picker.PickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    HorizontalScrollView imageScroll;
    LinearLayout imageLayout;
    LinkedList<View> thumbnails = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<String> thumbnailsPaths = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void onPickedSuccessfully(final ArrayList<ImageEntry> images) {
        imageLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_layout);
        imageScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_scroll);
        imageLayout.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        for(ImageEntry image : images){
            if (imageCount < 5) {
                imageCount++;
                imageScroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                View view = viewBuilder.createThumbnail(getActivity(), image.path);
                thumbnails.add(view);
                thumbnailsPaths.add(image.path);
                view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
                imageLayout.addView(view);
                MainActivity.imageArray.add(image.path);
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is what do I need to do to be able to load images taken from the gallery. At the moment they only show as empty, thanks

Comment: so what is `viewBuilder` exactly?